# Could not stop the xxx Service on Local Computer

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that works fine but When i try to stop it from the Services console, it raises this error:

> ```
> ---------------------------
> Services
> ---------------------------
> Windows could not stop the xxx service on Local Computer.
> The service did not return an error. 
> This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error.
> If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.
> ```

My code:

```
      protected override void OnStop()
      {
         // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        IvrApplication.StopImmediate();
      }
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Collections.Concurrent;
     using System.Text;
     using VoiceElements.Common;
     using VoiceElements.Client;
     using System.Threading;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Net.Sockets;
     using System.Configuration;

namespace VoiceApp
{
   public class IvrApplication
   {
       private static object s_SyncVar = new object();
      // private static ObjectPool<InboundLine> _linepool = new ObjectPool<InboundLine>(() => new InboundLine());
    //private static int _maxLineInstances = 0;
    public static object SyncVar
    {
        get { return IvrApplication.s_SyncVar; }
    }

    private static Log s_Log;
    public static Log Log
    {
        get { return s_Log; }
    }

    private static State s_State;

    public static State State
    {
        get { return s_State; }
    }

    private static Thread s_MainCodeThread;

    public static Thread MainCodeThread
    {
        get { return s_MainCodeThread; }
    }

    private static AutoResetEvent s_ThreadEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public static AutoResetEvent ThreadEvent
    {
        get { return s_ThreadEvent; }
    }

    private static string s_WorkingFolder = null;

    public static string WorkingFolder
    {
        get { return s_WorkingFolder; }
    }



    static IvrApplication()
    {
        // Constructor
        s_Log = new Log("IvrApplication.Log");
        Log.Write("IvrApplication Constructor Complete");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ExceptionObject is Exception)
        {
            Log.WriteException((Exception)e.ExceptionObject, "Domain Level Unhandled Exception");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Write("Domain Level Unhandled Exception - No Exception Object");
        }
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        lock (SyncVar)
        {
            if (State == State.Stopped)
            {
                s_State = State.Starting;
                ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(MainCode);
                s_MainCodeThread = new Thread(ts);
                s_MainCodeThread.Name = "IvrApplication";
                s_MainCodeThread.Start();
                Log.Write("IvrApplication Starting...");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Write("IvrApplication is in the " + State.ToString() + " state.  Cannot start IvrApplication at this time.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StopImmediate()
    {
        lock (SyncVar)
        {
            if (State == State.Running || State == State.StoppingControlled)
            {
                s_State = State.StoppingImmediate;
                ThreadEvent.Set();
                Log.Write("IvrApplication StoppingImmediate.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Write("IvrApplication is in the " + State.ToString() + " state.  Cannot stop IvrApplication at this time.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StopControlled()
    {
        lock (SyncVar)
        {
            if (State == State.Running)
            {
                s_State = State.StoppingControlled;
                ThreadEvent.Set();
                Log.Write("IvrApplication StoppingControlled.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Write("IvrApplication is in the " + State.ToString() + " state.  Cannot stop IvrApplication at this time.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static TelephonyServer s_TelephonyServer = null;

    public static void MainCode()
    {

        try
        {
            s_WorkingFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() Starting...");

            // Start Other Threads...
            try
            {
                // UPDATE YOUR SERVER ADDRESS HERE
                System.Net.IPAddress[] ips = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["veserver"]);

                if (ips == null || ips.Length == 0) throw new Exception("Error: Could not resolve Telephony Server specified!");

                string sIpaddress = @"gtcp://" + ips[0].ToString() + ":54331";
                Log.Write("Connecting to: {0}", sIpaddress);

                // CHANGE YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD HERE
                s_TelephonyServer = new TelephonyServer(sIpaddress, "username", "password");

                //create object pool for line instance object that get used in the Newcall Event handler

                // CHANGE YOUR CACHE MODE HERE
                //
                // Client Session mode means that the server will stream and cache the files to/from your client machine.
                // Files are flushed after you disconnect.
                //
                // Server mode means that the files reside on the server and will use the full path name to find them there.
                // Server mode can only be used on your own dedicate VE server.

                //s_TelephonyServer.CacheMode = VoiceElements.Interface.CacheMode.ClientSession;
                s_TelephonyServer.CacheMode = VoiceElements.Interface.CacheMode.Server;


                // SUBSCRIBE to the new call event.
                s_TelephonyServer.NewCall += new VoiceElements.Client.NewCall(s_TelephonyServer_NewCall);
                s_TelephonyServer.RegisterDNIS();

                // Subscribe to the connection events to allow you to reconnect if something happens to the internet connection.
                // If you are running your own VE server, this is less likely to happen except when you restart your VE server.
                s_TelephonyServer.ConnectionLost += new ConnectionLost(s_TelephonyServer_ConnectionLost);
                s_TelephonyServer.ConnectionRestored += new ConnectionRestored(s_TelephonyServer_ConnectionRestored);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (s_TelephonyServer != null)
                    {
                        s_TelephonyServer.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }

                Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() Exception: " + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }

            Log.Write("VoiceElementsClient Version: {0}", s_TelephonyServer.GetClientVersion());
            Log.Write("VoiceElementsServer Version: {0}", s_TelephonyServer.GetServerVersion());

            lock (SyncVar)
            {
                s_State = State.Running;
            }

            Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() Running...");

            while (true)
            {

                // Waits for some asyncronous event.
                ThreadEvent.WaitOne(10000, false);

                // At this point you are in control.  You can farm out calls from a database, 
                // or you could code the IvrInteractive Form and create a GUI for handling you calls.
                // Follow the example from the Sampler on how to make an outbound class for new calls.

                lock (SyncVar)
                {
                    if (State != State.Running) break;
                }
            }

            s_TelephonyServer.Dispose();
            s_TelephonyServer = null;

            // Must be shutting down...

            if (State == State.StoppingControlled)
            {
                Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() StoppingControlled...");
            }

            if (State == State.StoppingImmediate)
            {
                Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() StoppingImmediate...");
            }

            lock (SyncVar)
            {
                s_State = State.Stopped;
                Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() Stopped.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write("IvrApplication::MainCode() Exception" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            s_State = State.Stopped;
        }
        finally
        {
            s_MainCodeThread = null;
        }
    }

    static void s_TelephonyServer_ConnectionRestored(object sender, ConnectionRestoredEventArgs e)
    {

        // When the connection is restored you must reset your cache mode and re-register the DNIS.

        s_TelephonyServer.CacheMode = VoiceElements.Interface.CacheMode.ClientSession;
        //s_TelephonyServer.CacheMode = VoiceElements.Interface.CacheMode.Server;
        s_TelephonyServer.RegisterDNIS();

        Log.Write("The Connection to the server was successfully restored!");

    }

    static void s_TelephonyServer_ConnectionLost(object sender, ConnectionLostEventArgs e)
    {

        // You could also send an email to yourself to let you know that the server was down.
        Log.Write("The Connection to the server was lost.");
    }


    static void s_TelephonyServer_NewCall(object sender, VoiceElements.Client.NewCallEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle The New Call Here

        //Object Pool ***************************************************
        //if (_linepool.PoolCount() > _maxLineInstances)
        //{
        //    _maxLineInstances++;
        //    Log.Write("");
        //    Log.Write("Max Object Pool Size:{0}", _linepool.PoolCount().ToString());
        //    Log.Write("");
        //}
        //InboundLine s_InboundLine = _linepool.GetObject();
        //********************************************************

        InboundLine s_InboundLine = new InboundLine(); 
        s_InboundLine.TServer = s_TelephonyServer;
        s_InboundLine.Channel_Resource = e.ChannelResource;
        s_InboundLine.log = Log;
        s_InboundLine.RunScript();


//      _linepool.PutObject(s_InboundLine); //Object Pool

        //Threads per object ************************************
            //ThreadStart its = new ThreadStart(s_InboundLine.RunScript);
            //Thread s_InboundLineThread = new Thread(its);
            //s_InboundLineThread.Name = "Port"+e.ChannelResource.PortIndexer.ToString();
            //s_InboundLineThread.Start();
        //*********************************************************
    }


}
```

}

I tried to catch the exception in OnStop. I found the detail in event view is:

```
   Log Name:      Application
   Source:        IvrService
   Date:          11/4/2013 11:57:23 AM
   Event ID:      0
   Task Category: None
   Level:         Error
   Keywords:      Classic
   User:          N/A
   Computer:      xxx.corporate.my.com
   Description:
   Failed to stop service. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly  'VoiceElementsCommon, Version=8.3.12.111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   File name: 'VoiceElementsCommon, Version=8.3.12.111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at VoiceApp.IvrService.OnStop()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.DeferredStop()

    Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Running under executable  C:\source\VoiceApp\obj\Debug\VoiceApp.exe
     --- A detailed error log follows. 

    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    LOG: DisplayName = VoiceElementsCommon, Version=8.3.12.111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/source/VoiceApp/obj/Debug/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    Calling assembly : VoiceApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok...
    Event Xml:
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
      <System>
         <Provider Name="IvrService" />
           <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
           <Level>2</Level>
           <Task>0</Task>
           <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
           <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-11-04T16:57:23.000000000Z" />
           <EventRecordID>45872</EventRecordID>
           <Channel>Application</Channel>
           <Computer>xxx-desk.corporate.my.com</Computer>
           <Security />
       </System>
      <EventData>
      <Data>Failed to stop service. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or  assembly  'VoiceElementsCommon, Version=8.3.12.111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its  dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'VoiceElementsCommon, Version=8.3.12.111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

at VoiceApp.IvrService.OnStop()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.DeferredStop()

```
   Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
   Running under executable  C:\source\VoiceApp\obj\Debug\VoiceApp.exe
  --- A detailed error log follows. 

  === Pre-bind state information ===
   LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
   LOG: DisplayName = VoiceElementsCommon, Version=8.3.12.111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
   (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/VoiceApp/obj/Debug/
   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
   Calling assembly : VoiceApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok...</Data>
   </EventData>
   </Event>
```

Comment: how do you inizialize your EventWaitHandle? Do you attach it correctly to your threads?

Comment: what does your full code look like? I have seen problems with stopping a service if the start function was trying to do too much work

Comment: There is no need for `while (true)`. Your method gets stuck in the loop event after the event wait handle is signaled.

Comment: It is a telephone call project, it may have thousand of call at the same time. Each call is processed in each thread.

Comment: Hi, I added more details.

Comment: The fact that the stacktrace includes VoiceApp.IvrService.OnStop() but not IvrApplication.StopImmediate() would suggest that either something in that method or some static field/property/method in IvrApplication is causing it to try to load VoiceElementsCommon.dll.  Is it possible that this dll is missing or is getting deleted/moved at some stage?

Comment: In the IvrApplication.StopImmediate(), State and Log belong to VoiceElementsCommon.dll, should I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post all your code and it is difficult to understand the error.

The causes could be:

How you initialize your  `EventWaitHandle`: `AutoReset` or `ManualReset`and what you do in your thread to attach to it. [There](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find an example on how it should be done.

Your thread are doing time consuming stuffs and they [need more time to shutdown properly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
   this.RequestAdditionalTime(10000);
   IvrApplication.StopImmediate();
}
```

----------UPDATE---------

after you put the error logged I can bet you did not put all dependency dll in the folder where you service is.

Comment: So based by new code, any thought? Thanks.I used your code, still wrong.

Comment: @Love did you try to use RequestAdditionalTime?

Comment: @Love Look at the exemples I posted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I think you should use manualreset

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40512/discussion-between-love-and-giammin)

Comment: @@giammin, thanks. What is the folder where you service?Bin/debug? I already pull dlls and the error disappeared. But when I deploy the service on a remote server, the error comes back.

Comment: @Love the folder where you're service is deployed

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you've still got threads running after `StopImmediate()` is called.

EDIT:

From what I understand from you comments you are calling `IvrApplication.Start()` multiple times so `ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(MainCode);` is also called multiple times. This means you end up with a lot of threads all waiting for `ThreadEvent` to be signaled.
But, when you call `ThreadEvent.Set();` inside `StopImmediate()` what happens is that `ThreadEvent` is signaled but only one thread is released from the waiting event. The others still wait for the event.

What you need is a `ManualResetEvent` instead of an `AutoResetEvent` so that when you call `Set()` you release all waiting threads, not just the first one.

Instead of

```
private static AutoResetEvent s_ThreadEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

use

```
private static ManualResetEvent s_ThreadEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public static ManualResetEvent ThreadEvent
{
   get { return s_ThreadEvent; }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it is not working. I test it from service control panel. Just start it and then try stop it. In this test case, I think it only has one thread because IvrApplication.Start() was only called once rather than multiple times. Why it is still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

You need to add the method override:

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("On Shutdonw.");
    timer.Stop();
    //Add your code for release memory
}
```